# Using npm modules with TypeScript - can't even get the simplest example working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, typescript

I would like to use npm modules within a Typescript program. Fortunately, I came across [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/demo-typescript-node-minimal) which looks very easy and does indeed seem to work. I figured I would try and add another package, just to get the hang of it. So I [forked it](https://github.com/dumbmatter/demo-typescript-node-minimal) and made [one relatively simple commit](https://github.com/dumbmatter/demo-typescript-node-minimal/commit/cdc0d1233476d92bb2e64de6b79417d69f31bdad).

Here's all the things I did in my commit:

1. Added `pubsub-js` to my dependencies in `package.json`, so it will install on `npm install`.
2. Set up `tsd`, used it to install the TypeScript definition for `pubsub-js`, and set it to automatically run on `npm install`.
3. Modified `index.ts` to include the installed definition:

   ```
   /// <reference path="./typings/pubsubjs/pubsub.d.ts" />
   ```

   and to import the installed package:

   ```
   import PubSub = require('pubsub-js');
   ```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get this error:

```
$ npm install
$ npm test
> demo-typescript-node-minimal@0.0.1 test /home/dumbmatter/projects/mini/demo-typescript-node-minimal
> tsc index.ts --module commonjs && node ./index

index.ts(10,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'pubsub-js'.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

(If you want to it for yourself, [clone my repo](https://github.com/dumbmatter/demo-typescript-node-minimal), run `npm install`, and then `npm test`.)

And I want to reiterate, the original version (without my commit, straight from [the original repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/demo-typescript-node-minimal)) does in fact work:

```
$ git checkout d002c0dffc9d9f65aca465b0fc6a279bcd23202d
$ npm test

> demo-typescript-node-minimal@0.0.1 test /home/dumbmatter/projects/mini/demo-typescript-node-minimal
> tsc index.ts --module commonjs; node ./index

[ 'abc', index: 0, input: 'abcdefgh' ]
Hello Dave
```

So what gives? Why did my attempt fail so miserably?

I would also appreciate any advice on the wisdom of using npm packages in TypeScript in general. Is it just to error prone for real use? If so, and you found yourself in the situation where you wanted some generic pubsub library in a TypeScript program you were using... what would you do? Write your own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `pubsub.d.ts` doesn't contain a definition for the CommonJS module `"pubsub-js"` (instead it only defines a global object `PubSubJS`).

The best fix would be to edit that file; at the bottom add:

```
declare module "pubsub-js" {
  export = PubSub;
}
```

Most .d.ts files already include such a definition when a CommonJS or AMD module is available for a given package.

Comment: Damn, you answered so fast that Stack Overflow won't let me accept it yet!